# Codeigniter: Returning variable between functions

Tags: php, codeigniter, return-value

Here is my problem, is all ok with my code, just want to show the error message when the user upload a not allowed size/type image, is all in the controller or i need to create a model to pass the $error variable?:

```
public function upload_face1($file1, $id){
    $config['upload_path'] = '././assets/administrador/images/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_width'] = '470';
    $config['max_height'] = '276';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload($file1)) {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors()); // The $error Variable that don't display in my view, I can't return it to the function editMetatags() to load the view from there
        return $error;
    } else {
        $register = $this->mmetatags->catchFace1($id);
        unlink('././assets/admin/images/'.$register->face1);
        $file_info = $this->upload->data();
        $save = $file_info['file_name'];
        $this->mmetatags->editFace1($id, $save);
        return true;
    }
}

public function editMetatags($d){
    $param["cod_meta"] = $d;
    $param['title'] = $this->input->post("title");
    $param['description'] = $this->input->post("description");
    $param['keywords'] = $this->input->post("keywords");

    if (isset($_FILES['face1']) && $_FILES['face1']['name'] != ''){
        $file1 = $this->upload_face1('face1', $d); //The file is there, but It wasn't uploaded beacause don't have the allowed size or type.
    }

    $data['error'] = $error; // Here is the variable "returned"
    $data['mensaje'] = 'success :D';
    $data["metatags"] = $this->mmetatags->loadMetatags($d);
    $this->load->view('administrador/editmetatags', $data, $error);

}
```

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to get the errors to the view would be to use CodeIgniter's Load::vars() like this:

```
$this->load->vars(array('upload_errors' => $this->upload->display_errors()));
```

Then in your view:

```
if( isset($upload_errors) )
      echo $upload_errors;
```